# Find the domain of the sequence in which it converges uniformly.

Tags: uniform-convergence

Let $f_n(x)={x^n\over n}+1$. I need  to find the domain of it's uniform convergence. I tried the $M_n$-test. So, I got the point limit $f(x)=1$ when $x\in [0,1]$. For $x>1$ the point limit wont exist, hence no question of uniform convergence arises. Thus, the convergence in uniform in $[0,1]$. That goes right now hopefully.

**UPDATE** Also, now I observed the convergence will hold uniformly in $[-1,0]$ by similar argument. For $\vert x\vert >1$, the point limit won't exist. So, the domain of uniform convergence should be $[-1,1]$

Comment: $f_n(2)$ certainly doesn't converge. You might want add some details to your reasoning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not true. I'll only discuss the sequence for nonnegative $x$. The negative $x$ I'll leave it for you. For $x>1$ the limit is infinity (why?). So $f(x) =1$ cannot be the limit function for ALL $x$! For $x=1$ the limit is $1$. For $x\in[0,1)$ we have $f(x) =1$. That was all pointwise limits.

Now let's check uniform convergence where there is pointwise convergence so only on $[0,1]$. So $f(x) =1$ and
\begin{align} 
\sup_{x\in[0,1]} |f_n(x) -  f(x) |\leq \frac{1} {n} \to 0
\end{align} 
So uniform convergence on $[0,1]$. Now do the negative half line yourself and conclude.

Comment: _For x>1x>1 the limit is infinity (why?)_ : Yup true That is because for x>1, we obtain the indeterminate form. On applying L Hopital's rule, I got infinity Got it. Thanks.

Comment: @ShatabdiSinha good!

Comment: Sir, by similar argument would it not be correct to say that the convergence is also uniform in [-1,0]..? Because for values of x<-1 the point limit should not exist? Is this right sir?

Comment: @ShatabdiSinha totally correct! Keep up the good work!

Comment: Thankfully I got it right. Thank you for your appreciation.